# Aliases in GNOME Terminal 2.16.0 are not being set

Tags: bash, terminal, alias, csh

The alias command is not working and I believe I am following the correct syntax for example:

```
alias np='ls -la'
```

I have also tried speech marks:

```
alias np="ls -la"
```

In both cases the response to np is

```
np: Command not found.
```

However, if I run alias with no arguments it does list current aliases (for the record 'nl' is not already listed).

Comment: What do you get if you type `nl` in your command line after setting the alias? (btw, "one" or "L"?)

Comment: edit: Apologies I put nl as an example here only, whilst that is already a command. However when I used np, I recieve "np: Command not found."

It is an L.

Comment: This is quite weird. Have you tried with different alias? Like `alias hello="echo hi"` or something like that?

Comment: The same result unfortunately!

Comment: Have you tried with different users?

Comment: I believe another user on the system is able to do the above. I'm not granted sudo permissions.

Comment: We're using csh, so the equals sign is not necessary.

Comment: It shouldn't be a `sudo permissions` problem. I am sorry to say I have no clue of what can be going on. Would recommend to test different commands and users... and hope somebody comes with broader view of it.

Comment: So did it work to you without equals?

Comment: It's not just that the equals is not necessary, it's that it is not allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using csh, an equals sign is not allowed. The above should be written:

```
alias np "ls -la"
```